# JavaScript and CSS cached and not updating not updating from WAMP server even though "view source" shows most recent file

Tags: javascript, css, cache, wampserver, wamp

I have a WAMP server with PHP 7.2.10. When I change a file, for example `.css`, the changes is not visible in browser. When I "view source" via my browser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) I get the updated latest version of the code.  Even then, the browser doesn't display update the appearance of my site.

I was thinking that if it were just a caching problem, the old version of file should be show in "view source", shouldn't it?

I have the same problem with JavaScript. I have simple jQuery code (alert after clicking the selected class), it is visible in source code of site inside browser, but when I click the selected class, nothing happens.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is ctrl+F5. This is a cache refresh.

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking that if it were just a caching problem, the old version of file should be show in "view source", shouldn't it?

View Source will actually show you the new version of the file, not the old version. [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282010/how-to-view-html-source-without-refreshing-the-page-in-chrome) and [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611617/can-firefoxs-view-source-be-set-to-not-make-a-new-get-request) both refresh the resource when you View Source, which means you would see the new version.

To ensure you always get the fresh version, you can do one of two things:

- Check your `Cache-Control` HTTP header and make sure your server is serving a response such as `no-cache`

or

- Open up the dev tools of your browser, go to the Network section and click "Disable Cache" to disable caching while dev tools is open

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you call up the specific document (localhost/example/cssfile.css) in yuor browser, then "refresh" it, the document changes will update and take effect. Not sure if this is a Window's glitch, or a WAMP glitch. But that has consistantly resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I don't think this is a glitch, just a caching issue, but I could be wrong. The reason this refreshing trick works is that the `refresh` button instructs the browser to fetch a fresh version of the resource, rather than relying on the standard caching behavior. Then once the browser has the new version loaded, it will use it when other pages request the same resource.

Comment: I was having the problem while I was doing quick edits to my file. Change, test, change, test... but because this edits were within seconds of eachother, normal caching still thought it had a 'new' version. I could see the old one in the browser, hit refresh, and ta-da! the new doc would load.

Comment: Have you considered serving your dev environment using `Cache-Control: no-cache` headers? Might save some time over fiddling with the refresh button.

Comment: I don't use dev tools, I code everything old school with TextPad (similar to NotePad). I will try the view source trick though (fewer steps). Thanks. :)

Comment: To clarify, when I say "dev environment" I don't mean your editor, I mean your local HTTP/backend server setup that you use for development.

Comment: "Open up the dev tools of your browser, go to the Network section and click 'Disable Cache' to disable caching while dev tools is open"
Except that I don't open dev tools to code. I code old school. So, it's not open while I'm working.... but thank you for being concerned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87163/discussion-between-maximillian-laumeister-and-elbrant).

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are using PHP, you can put this code:

```
"?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"
```

in case of the link tag, at the final of the href param like this example:

```
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='./inc/mystyle.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>'>"
```

that will result in your code something like this:

```
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='./inc/mystyle.css?v=1553116856>"
```

that will do a cache refresh always;

in case of a script tag is the same thing but in the src param like this:

```
<script src="./inc/myscript.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

and will result in the same way:

```
<script src="./inc/myscript.js?v=1553116856"></script>
```

Try it! I espect that this help you!

Comment: This looked like an elegant solution and at first didn't work, at least on my test platform. Chrome browser Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit), localhost XAMPP control version v3.2.4 XAMPP Version: 7.3.6 But I was wrong, this seems to work with some waiting time. `<script src="js/ovEndDate.js?nocache=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>`

Comment: If you clean the cache of your browser or run it on an incognito window will work perfectly!